# Validating an url in nightwatch using `expect` returns an error message

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am using async await in my nightwatch test. i am using `expect` assertion to validate the url. for some reasons its returning an error message.  please find the code and an error message below. if anyone can help please ?

I have followed this document but not sure why failing- https://nightwatchjs.org/api/expect/#expect-url-

```
await browser.expect.url().to.contain(await `${data.Url}`);
```

````
returned error message as below 
Error: Unknown property: "then". Please consult docs at: http://nightwatchjs.org/api.```
````

Comment: Hello! May I know what is the purpose of `await` inside contain? data is a local object?

Comment: `data` is a json object. The test stops if i don't put the await inside it. however i have found the solution to my problem. The problem is , it didn't like `await` in the staring line of my code. once i remove it works wonderfully.  here is the solution.                                                                                                                                 
 `browser.expect.url().to.contain(await `${data.Url}`).after(3000);`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my code. The problem is , it didn't like `await` in the staring line of my code. once i removed that. it works wonderfully. here is the solution.

`browser.expect.url().to.contain(await ${data.Url}).after(3000);`